# Entity Framework projected column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am looking to exposed an entity collection as an OData feed only for query. Issue I have is that the data type exposed is not matching one-to-one as on the database. like for e.g.

I have a Property on my entity as `MaterialId` but this is made up of `MATERIAL` + `MATERIAL_GRP_1`

is there a way to do this in EF .net core2.1

I have tried to use

`entity.Property(p => p.MaterialId).HasComputedColumnSql("[MATERIAL] + '-' + [MATERIAL_GROUP_1]");`

however when I am querying for this entity the generated SQL on the database is looking for the `$it.MaterialId`  which fails as there is no such column on the database table.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: I think the issue is that HasComputedColumnSql actually creates a computed column in your database table. Have you run a migration to add the computed column?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend different way

```
  public class Contact
    {

        public string MATERIAL { get; set; }
        public string MATERIAL_GROUP_1 { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string MaterialId => $"{MATERIAL} {MATERIAL_GROUP_1}";


    }
```

Comment: Thanks!, but I am looking to see if I can manage it in the Fluent API instead of changing my contract.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `entities`, where every `entity` has some properties. You want to select several (or all) items from this sequence and transform every `entity` into an object of a similar class. For this we use `Select`

I'm not sure if your sequence is `AsEnumerable` or `AsQueryable`. The difference is that an `IQueryable` is to be executed on a different process, usually a database, while the `IEnumerable` is to be performed on your local process.

### AsEnumerable

Let's first describe the `IEnumerable`. Suppose your input sequence is a sequence of `Persons` and your output is a sequence of `SimplePersons`. Although they look similar there is a slight difference

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
class SimplePerson
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FullName {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose you have a sequence of Persons and you want to convert them into a sequence of SimplePersons: every `Person` should become one `SimplePerson` where the `FullName` is the concatenation of the persons's `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Use 'Select`to project every`Person`into a`SimplePerson`:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ...
IEnumerable<SimplePerson> simplePersons = persons
   // convert every Person into a SimplePerson:
   .Select(person => new SimplePerson()
   {
        Id = person.Id,
        FullName = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
   });
```

Voila! Simple comme bonjour!

### AsQueryable

If your input sequence of Persons is `AsQueryable`, then usually the query has to be performed by a different process. This is quite often a Database Management System. The `IQueryable` has an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` represents the query that must be executed. The `Provider` knows who must execute the query (which DBMS), it knows how to translate the `Expression` into a language that the executor of the query (SQL) and it knows how to communicate with the executor.

When the `IQueryable` is to be enumerated, either implicitly by using `foreach`, `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Max()` etc, or explicitly by using `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`.

The `Provider` translates the `Expression` into the language that the DBMS understands and executes the query. The result is converted into an IEnumerable of which  `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` are called

The problem is that SQL does not know your `SimplePerson`, hence it can't call its constructor.

One of the solutions would be to call `ToList()` before projecting the `Persons` into `SimplePersons`:

```
IEnumerable<SimplePerson> FetchSimplePersons()
{
    IQueryable<Person> persons = ...
    IEnumerable<SimplePerson> simplePersons = simplePersons
        // execute the query, move persons to local process
        .ToList()
        // convert every Person into a SimplePerson:
        .Select(person => new SimplePerson()
        {
            Id = person.Id,
            FullName = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
        });
    return simplePersons;
}
```

However this would be a waste or processing power if you don't want to use all simplePersons:

```
bool personsAvailable = FetchSimplePersons().Any()
```

First you fetch all 1000 Persons, and then you only check if there is at least one `SimplePerson`. What a waste of processing power!

For this `AsEnumerable()` is invented. This function fetches the queryable data in a smart way, so that if you don't use all fetched data, the waste is not too big. There are several strategies to limit the loss. The actual used strategy differs per `Provider`.

An often used strategy for `AsEnumerable` would be to fetch the `Persons` per page of, say 100 `Persons`. If you use only a few of them, you'll throw away all other fetched `Persons` on the page, but at least that is better than throwing away all 1000 `Persons`

```
IEnumerable<SimplePerson> FetchSimplePersons()
{
    IQueryable<Person> persons = ...
    IEnumerable<SimplePerson> simplePersons = simplePersons
        // execute the query per page:
        .AsEnumerable()

        // convert every fetched Person into a SimplePerson:
        .Select(person => new SimplePerson()
        {
            Id = person.Id,
            FullName = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
        });
    return simplePersons;
}
```

`AsEnumerable()` is smart enough to fetch the next page if `MoveNext` is called at the last item of the current Page. So for users it is similar as ToList().

Comment: First, thank you for a detailed explanation, I definitely oversimplified my question. When I mentioned entity collection, I actually have it in a DB and I am using OData to expose it. my OData Entity looks a bit different from the Table structure and this is where I am having issues in connecting the two. Can this be done such that the actual query generated by the EF Core is taking care of the conversions? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea next time to show the relevant parts of your classes, at least whether they are `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`, and the releationship between the classes. Now I quite often have to guess it: is it a one-to-many or many-to-many? What are the relevant properties? etc

Comment: Well, my situation is bit different & to some extent strange. I have an Entity Model assembly that defines how various source system have to expose their information. Kind of a `Interface`  `DataCotract`. Now Team where I work do not have much leverage to get a view created that can map to this `DataCotract`. So that only leaves me with a place within `DbContext` to work on such things. is it even possible to create a runtime attribute without mapping the actual coulmn one to one with the entity attributes.